# Drawing with a macro

Tags: metapost

I have just began using MetaPost and I would liked to be able to put a grid on my images, so I could easily read coordinates from it. I would liked to write a macro, that I could import while creating new figures and draw a grid with a single command.

My grid macro is the following:

```
def drawgrid(expr width, height, nx, ny) = 
begingroup
ny * u = width;
nx * v = height;
lu = 2 * u;
lv = 2 * v;
my = floor(width / lu);
mx = floor(height / lv);

for y = 0 upto nx:
    draw (0,y*v)--(width,y*v);
endfor
for y = 0 upto mx:
    draw (0,y*lv)--(width,y*lv) withpen pencircle scaled 2;
    label(decimal(y*lv/v), (-0.5u, y*lv));
endfor

for x = 0 upto my:
    draw (x*lu,0)--(x*lu,height) withpen pencircle scaled 2;
    label(decimal(x*lu/u), (x*lu, -0.5v));
endfor
for x = 0 upto ny:
    draw (x*u,0)--(x*u,height);
endfor
endgroup
enddef;
end
```

It works fine, when called from the same file (grid.mp), but fails to draw anything if I call it from my another figure. My other figures code is:

```
input grid

beginfig(1); textwidth := 345.0;
width := 0.5textwidth;
radius := 0.25width;

fill fullcircle scaled radius withcolor blob;
draw fullcircle scaled radius withcolor blobBorder;
clip currentpicture to (-0.5,-0.5)--(-0.5,0.5radius+0.5)--(0.5radius+0.5,0.5radius+0.5)--(0.5radius+0.5,-0.5)--cycle;
draw (-0.5, 0.5radius)--(-0.5, -0.5)--(0.5radius, -0.5) withcolor blobBorder;
draw (0, 0)--(0.25radius, 0.45radius);
drawgrid(width,width,2,2);
endfig
end
```

It does not draw anything (even do not produce an .1 file). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Additionnally, if you want to make some variables local, it is not enough to include them in `begingroup`… `endgroup`. You also have to use the `save` instruction. For example, `save M; pair M;` if you want to make a `M` pair variable local into a group.

Comment: Colors _blob_ and _blobBorder_ are not defined either…

Comment: … and you shouldn't include and `end` command at the end of your `grid.mp`. It makes MetaPost ignore whatever is written after it, included in the main file. It's probably the main cause of the problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a macro file following my comments:

```
def drawgrid(expr width, height, nx, ny) = 
begingroup
  save u, v, mx, my, lv, lu;
  ny * u = width;
  nx * v = height;
  lu = 2 * u;
  lv = 2 * v;
  my = floor(width / lu);
  mx = floor(height / lv);

  for y = 0 upto nx:
    draw (0,y*v)--(width,y*v);
  endfor
  for y = 0 upto mx:
    draw (0,y*lv)--(width,y*lv) withpen pencircle scaled 2;
    label(decimal(y*lv/v), (-0.5u, y*lv));
  endfor

  for x = 0 upto my:
    draw (x*lu,0)--(x*lu,height) withpen pencircle scaled 2;
    label(decimal(x*lu/u), (x*lu, -0.5v));
  endfor
  for x = 0 upto ny:
    draw (x*u,0)--(x*u,height);
  endfor
endgroup
enddef;
```

And here is a main file that produces something (not sure of if the drawing is what was intended):

```
input grid;

beginfig(1); 
textwidth := 345.0;
width := 0.5textwidth;
radius := 0.25width;
color blob, blobBorder; blob=red; blobBorder = blue;
draw fullcircle scaled radius withcolor blob;
draw fullcircle scaled radius withcolor blobBorder;
clip currentpicture to (-0.5,-0.5)--(-0.5,0.5radius+0.5)--(0.5radius+0.5,0.5radius+0.5)--(0.5radius+0.5,-0.5)--cycle;
draw (-0.5, 0.5radius)--(-0.5, -0.5)--(0.5radius, -0.5) withcolor blobBorder;
draw (0, 0)--(0.25radius, 0.45radius);
drawgrid(width,width,2,2);
endfig;
end;
```

The result:

[image]